# Adding Array of Strings as Column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Questions] (    
    [QuestionID] INT           NOT NULL,
    [Question]   NCHAR (300)   NOT NULL,
    [Choices]    NCHAR [200]   NOT NULL, -- something like this
    [Answer]     NCHAR (200)   NOT NULL, -- one of the indexes in Choices
);
```

I have multiple choice questions that I am storing into a database, and I would like to keep all information grouped together in one table. The `QuestionID` and `Question` is not difficult, but I don't know how to set up some array of strings to store the possible answers (A: one, B: two, C: three, D: four) into the `Choices` column and to have the `Answer` column store a copy of the correct choice or the index of the correct choice (whichever is easier).

Many responses I've read quickly suggest that a **text file** would be easier, however, that is **not** something I want to do.

This is a personal project (not to be used in any real production), so it doesn't have to be secure or safe by any means. Any hack-y solutions that work are perfect.

Comment: It very depends on the database you're using. I'm afraid it's not possible to  help you without such information. Unless you would use 1:N relation, which would be the best solution and possible in all relational databases. But you wrote you don't like it.

Comment: A 1:N relation refers to using a text file, then? If it really is the only choice, I will use it. The reason I said I wouldn't like it is all of the text processing I have to do in my C# code. The database queries are much easier to write and I don't have to worry about malformed data

Comment: What's the text file in a relation with the database? I definitely didn't mean anything like that. 1:N relation means 2 tables, where there is one column in the first table containing relation to the primary key of another table.

Comment: But as I wrote you didn't say, what database you're using, which is the most important information, since arrays are implemented in various databases differently. Anyway it's not a good solution for many reasons and you should avoid it in a favor of 1:N relation always when possible.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you said- my apologies

Comment: But you still didn't answer what database engine you're using. And I asked twice already, so I'll try it for third time: what database engine are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 12.00.2000

Comment: I suspect you're not comfortable with writing join logic. This is a good opportunity to learn it. In your case though, I'm not sure you gain a lot by splitting into two tables. If your questions always have four possible responses it doesn't seem like a horrible violation of normal forms to just include them all in a single row. It *is* still a bad habit to get into.

Comment: As I already wrote, **text file is nonsense**. I don't know what terminology you're using, but it definitely doesn't mean anything in a relation to the database. Nobody suggested you to use a something called "text file". Do it like others
 suggest, it will save you a lot of problems later. In the end, it'll be more simple than trying to use arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a separate Answers table, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Answers] (
    [AnswerID]   INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [QuestionID] INT NOT NULL, -- linked to Questions.QuestionID
    [Choice]     NCHAR [200]
);
```

Then you make the answer field in the Questions table link to the AnswerID of the actual answer.

(N.B. this is *not* a text file, this is a second linked table)

*ETA*

You would change your question table to this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Questions] (    
    [QuestionID] INT           NOT NULL,
    [Question]   NCHAR (300)   NOT NULL,
    [AnswerID]   INT        -- this is linked to Answers.AnswerID
);
```

Questions.AnswerID is the index of the row in Answers which has the correct answer for the Question.

Comment: So how will the choices be stores? as their own separate column? Columns choiceA, choiceB, choiceC, choiceD?

Comment: Definitely not! You would need to add a column always when you need to add a choice. That's very bad design. Each choice should be a row.

Comment: This is exactly what I suggested in my comments. It's a proper normalized design for such use case.

Comment: @user3465668 I expanded my answer to show how your Questions table should be structured.

Comment: Oh, and your Questions.QuestionID column should be a PRIMARY KEY also.

Comment: I would like to add that if these questions really are multiple choice, the `AnswerID` probably should be `CHAR(1)` and not INT. The primary key for the Answers table would then be a composite one: `(QuestionID, AnswerID)`.  The reason for these changes is that it makes the AnswerID closer to the actual data -- you can more easily see that a user chose choice C. However many people hate composite primary keys.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The more I think of it, this design makes sense. Plus, it allows for more/less than 4 choices. And thank you @RossPresser, you are right